# Android how to make rounded dotted line

Tags: android

how to make rounded dotted line by using XML or customized view. I am able to make dashed line by using xml but dash in line are rectangle shape but I want to make it rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761184/android-drawing-tiled-bitmaps-with-bottom-or-some-other-alignments-similar-to-c)

```
class MyBitmapDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    private boolean mRebuildShader = true;
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mRebuildShader) {
            mPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT));
            mRebuildShader = false;
        }

        // Translate down by the remainder
        mMatrix.setTranslate(0, getBounds().bottom % getIntrinsicHeight());
        canvas.save();
        canvas.setMatrix(mMatrix);
        canvas.drawRect(getBounds(), mPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

view.setBackgroundDrawable(new MyBitmapDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley).getBitmap()));
```